# Python BeautifulSoup encoding

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a code to read the html and modify some text using Beatiful Soup. It works fine but when I read the output, this part of my html file is changed automatically:

Original : `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=**iso-8859-1**" />`

Modified by itself: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=**utf-8**" />`

I don't want any of the file contents to change automatically. Can someone help me with this.

Here is my code:

```
import re

import sys

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

f = open(sys.argv[1],"rw")
data = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

comma = re.compile(',')

for t in soup.findAll(text=comma): t.replaceWith(t.replace(',', '&sbquo'))

print soup
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup takes some liberties with html, like automatically correcting things it perceives to be a problem.  It might be worth using lxml, it has a very similar feature set and should leave everything unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
print soup.__str__("ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It works. I have one more question. soup.findAll(text=comma) finds all text including comments in html page. <! text > . How can I get text excluding commented text. Please help me on this. I am stuck because of this issue.